# How to do UDP multi chat server socket program using threading?

Tags: multithreading, udp, python-sockets

I am completely new to network and socket programming. I have tried some code; say I have 3 clients and a server c1 messages and it goes through server and reflected in c2 and c3.

My problem:

1. I don't want to see my own message (if I say "hi" it's showing for me also but it should be shown in c2 and c3 only).
2. is there a way like only c2 can see a message and not c3 when c1 sends it
3. unable to do this in Python and error is shown, so how can be it done in Python 3

server.py

```
import socket
import time

host = ''
port = 5020

clients = []

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
a=s.bind((host, port))
#s.setblocking(0)

quitting = False
print "Server Started."
print("socket binded to %s" % (port))
while not quitting:
    try:
        data, addr = s.recvfrom(1024)
        if "Quit" in str(data):
            quitting = True
        if addr not in clients:
            clients.append(addr)
            #print clients
        for client in clients:
            if not a:# tried this for broadcasting to others not c1

                s.sendto(data, client)

        print time.ctime(time.time()) + str(addr) + ": :" + str(data)

    except:
        pass
s.close()
```

This is Python 2 code.

client.py

```
enter code hereimport socket
import threading
import time


shutdown = False

def receving(name, sock):
    while not shutdown:
        try:

            while True:
                data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024)

                print str(data)
        except:
            pass


host = ''
port = 5020

server = ('',5020)

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.bind((host, port))
#s.setblocking(0)

for i in range(5):
    threading.Thread(target=receving, args=("RecvThread",s)).start()


alias = raw_input("Name: ")
message = raw_input(alias + "-> ")
while message != 'q':
    if message != '':
        s.sendto(alias + ": " + message, server)

    message = raw_input(alias + "-> ")

    time.sleep(0.1)

shutdown = True

s.close()
```

The output am getting in server is correct the time and server message, but my problem is client output c1 message is shown in c1 itself.

```
 Name: c1
 c1-> hi
 c1-> c1: hi
```

see the 3rd line the message "hi" is shown to me also.

Comment: This seems to be a good question, but was rather marred by the chatty style, begging and txtspk: please see how much repair was necessary in the revision history. If full words are too much trouble for you to type, Stack Overflow may not be for you.

Comment: ok @halfer next time i try to improve to post a question

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
for client in clients:
   if not a:# tried this for broadcasting to others not c1

      s.sendto(data, client)
```

You can do this:

```
for client in clients:
   if client!=addr:# tried this for broadcasting to others not c1

       s.sendto(data, client)
```

Because address of every connected client is stored in *addr* variable when you do this:

```
data, addr = s.recvfrom(1024)
```